# Access trough ssh as a root

Tags: ssh, sudo, sudoers

I have a virtual machine with ssh access. Previously I logged in trough ssh as a root, but I tried to configure ssh access for users group. I followed the following tutorial: http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/how-do-i-permit-specific-users-ssh-access

I have created group "sshusers" and added "my-user" to "sshusers" group. Then I added the following entry to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
AllowGroups sshusers
```

Unfortunately I forgot to add "my-user" to sudoers.

Now I cannot login as root (since he is not in "sshusers" group) and I can not fix the configuration as a "my-user" (since he is not in sudoers).

Is it possible to fix this issue without having to reinstall system... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SSH access you can type the follwing

> su - [enter]

This will ask for the root password, typ it in and then you are a root user.

After that you can add you user to the sudoers group.

Comment: Lesson for today: never close your ssh session until you verify that everything is okay with new configuration :)